# How to calculate frequncy of elements using cumulative sum?

Tags: c++, cumulative-sum

Given `q` ranges, I want to calculate the frequency of each element in these ranges.

Input:

```
1 2 3
(n elements)

1 2 (1 2)
2 3 (2 3)
1 3 (1 2 3)
(ranges)
```

Output:

```
2 3 2
```

I do not understand this method:

```
while(t--){
    int l,r;
    cin>>l>>r;
    b[l]++;
    b[r+1]--;
}
for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
    b[i]=b[i-1]+b[i];
}
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't produce any output, and so can't possibly be a solution for the stated problem. Prepare a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It is the 1-dimension version of the "swee line algorithm".

So you're basically given an range of numbers, let's say `1` to `3`, and then a set of subranges, let's say `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, and `[1,3]`, and you want to compute the frequencies of each number in the input range.

Here's a "brute force" solution:

- You use a vector of frequencies, as big as the range of numbers, and initialized to zero.
- For each number in the subrange, you increment the frecuency in one.
- The good point of this algorithm is that, at the end of every pass, you already know the frequencies of each number.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/sa837Yaas)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // transform
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout

int main() {
    size_t number_of_elements{};
    std::cin >> number_of_elements;
    std::cout << "number of elements = " << number_of_elements << "\n";
    std::vector<int> v(number_of_elements);

    size_t number_of_ranges{};
    std::cin >> number_of_ranges;
    std::cout << "number of ranges = " << number_of_ranges << "\n";

    fmt::print("\nProcessing subranges, v = {}\n", v);
    while (number_of_ranges--) {
        size_t first{};
        size_t last{};
        std::cin >> first >> last;
        std::cout << "first = " << first << ", and last = " << last << ", ";
        std::transform(
            std::cbegin(v) + first - 1, std::cbegin(v) + last,
            std::begin(v) + first - 1,
            [](int i) { return i+1; });
        fmt::print("v = {}\n", v);
    }

    for (size_t i{0}; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "i: " << v[i] << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   number of elements = 3
//   number of ranges = 3
//   v = [0, 0, 0]
//   first = 1, and last = 2, v = [1, 1, 0]
//   first = 2, and last = 3, v = [1, 2, 1]
//   first = 1, and last = 3, v = [2, 3, 2]
```

The "sweep line algorithm" is more efficient:

- It also uses an extra vector `v`, with all the elements also initalized to zero.
- But, given a subrange `[first, last)`, it just increments `v[first]` and decrements `v[last]`. That is, it only leaves a mark where a subrange starts and ends.
- Lastly, once all the subranges are processed, it walks `v` computing the final frequencies as `v[i - 1] + v[i]`.

This is the algorithm's key point. Imagine you have a range from 1 to 5, and a subrange from 2 to 4:

- Before that final loop, `v = [0, 1, 0, 0, -1]`.
- `v[0]` will already be a frequency. The first position can only start a subrange, so its value will indicate how many subranges it belongs to. In this example, its value is zero.
- You compute frequencies from positions 2 to 5 (indexes 1 to 4), because you make use of `v[i - 1]`.
- `v[1] = v[0] + v[1] = 0 + 1 -> 1`. There is a subrange starting at position 2 (index 1). Had there been a subrange starting from 1 (index 0) as well, `v[1] = v[0] + v[1] = 1 + 1 -> 2`.
- `v[2] = v[1] + v[2] = 1 + 0 -> 1`. So we hadn't marked down anything for the position 3 (index 2), but here's where the cumulative sum fires in; we add up `v[1] = 1` meaning we are still part of the subrange started in position 2 (index 1).
- `v[3] = v[2] + v[3] = 1 + 0 -> 1`. Same story.
- `v[4] = v[3] + v[4] = 1 - 1 -> 0`. Here we are marking we are out of a subrange, hence the decrement; in this case, that comes to nullify the `v[3] = 1` that was saying position 5 (index 4) was still part of a previous subrange.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/hnWqxxbxd)

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <vector>

int main() {
    size_t number_of_elements{};
    std::cin >> number_of_elements;
    std::cout << "number of elements = " << number_of_elements << "\n";
    std::vector<int> v(number_of_elements);

    size_t number_of_ranges{};
    std::cin >> number_of_ranges;
    std::cout << "number of ranges = " << number_of_ranges << "\n";

    fmt::print("\nProcessing subranges, v = {}\n", v);
    while (number_of_ranges--) {
        size_t first{};
        size_t last{};
        std::cin >> first >> last;
        std::cout << "first = " << first << ", and last = " << last << ", ";
        v[first - 1]++;
        v[last]--;
        fmt::print("v = {}\n", v);
    }

    std::cout << "\nFinal pass\n";
    for (size_t i{1}; i < number_of_elements; ++i) {
        v[i] = v[i - 1] + v[i];
        fmt::print("v = {}\n", v);
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   number of elements = 3
//   number of ranges = 3
//   
//   Processing subranges, v = [0, 0, 0]
//   first = 1, and last = 2, v = [1, 0, -1]
//   first = 2, and last = 3, v = [1, 1, -1]
//   first = 1, and last = 3, v = [2, 1, -1]
//   
//   Final pass
//   v = [2, 3, -1]
//   v = [2, 3, 2]
```